# Approximation of functions in $L^p(R^d;L^\infty)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, approximation-theory

Assume that the function $f(x,y)\in L^p(R^d;L^\infty(B_R))$ with $1<p<\infty$, where $B_R:=\{y\in R^d: |y|\le R\}$. Can we find a class of functions $f_n\in C_b^2(R^d;L^\infty(B_R))$ such that
$$
\big\|\sup_{|y|\le R}|f_n(\cdot,y)-f(\cdot,y)|\big\|_{L^p}\to 0\quad as\quad  n\to\infty ??
$$

Comment: Have you tried to approximate $f$ with a linear combination of simple function first, and then to approximate each simple function with a smooth one?

Comment: I tried to approximate $f$ by functions of the form $f_n(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^ng_i(x)h_i(y)$. But is it true that we can get$$\|\sup_{|y|\le R}|f_n(\cdot,y)-f(\cdot,y)|\|_{L^p}\to 0???.$$

Comment: I think this should be true if the condition $f\in L^p(R^d, X)$ is understood in the sense that $f$ is [Bochner integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral) with exponent $p$.

Comment: The conclusion you mentioned seems to need the condition that $X$ is a reflective Banach space, is it right?

Comment: I don't think reflexivity is needed here, see e.g. Proposition 2.1.10 in the book [*Nonlinear Analysis*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=817BSSZj-CcC&source=gbs_navlinks_s) by Leszek Gasinski, Nikolaos S. Papageorgiou